# .NET Windows Form - Interact with a website's filedialog opened from webview2

Tags: winforms, webview2

I'm using webview2 in a .NET Framework Windows Forms application to automatically upload files to a website. The site only supports uploading one file at a time and we often have to upload hundreds of files. I used java script in the webview2 to execute the steps for the upload.

My problem is that to specify the file to upload I have to interact with a file dialog box that's opens on a button click from the website within the webview. I'm currently populating the path of the file to upload in the filedialog using SendKeys, which I think is a poor process.

Is there a way that I can interact with the filedialog that is created from the website through my Windows Forms application? If so how would I get started in figuring out how to do that?

Here's more detail on what I'm currently doing:

In the webview, to begin an upload you have to click a few checkboxes to choose upload options, which has to be done every time, so I run these commands first:

```
await webview2.ExecuteScriptAsync($"document.getElementById('SelectedTypeId').click();");
await webview2.ExecuteScriptAsync($"document.getElementById('AutoAcceptChkbox').click();");
```

Then, there's a command to click an upload button, which opens a file dialog:

```
await webview2.ExecuteScriptAsync($"document.getElementById('uploadFile').click();");
```

From here, I get the filedialog and use SendKeys.Send("Filepath to file") and SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}") to populate the file path and select the file.

Once the filedialog closes I have an additonal command to click the import button to begin the import.

The issue I have is with the filedialog. It's obviously not a great process to use SendKeys to populate the path to the file. Also, I have to make the application "wait" around the sendkeys actions so that the filedialog has time to come up and close out before moving forward, I'm betting at some point there will be errors if the application isn't waiting long enough.

Comment: Can't you use a `HttpClient`? It's made for cases like this.

Comment: I was already using webview2 for some other automation on the site and hadn't considered anything else. I'll take a look, thanks!